# Is there anyway to see if my users input is in a certain range?

Tags: java, if-statement, range, user-input

I'm taking some input from the user and I need to make sure there input is between the range 200-800. For all of my variable should I just make if statements or is there a shortcut?

```
System.out.print("SAT Math: ");
int satMath = kb.nextInt();
System.out.print("SAT Reading: ");
int satReading = kb.nextInt();
System.out.print("SAT Writing: ");
int satWriting = kb.nextInt();
//If score is out of range.
if (((satMath < 200 || satMath > 800) || (satReading < 200 || satReading > 800) || (satWriting < 200 || satWriting > 800)))
{
   System.out.println("Did not enter a value in range!");
   System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: There's no better way than what you have... Unless maybe you're using some kind of framework that performs validation (like JSF).  My guess is you're writing a simple command line program, in which case you've got it right already.

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed. Please don't use inappropriate tags as that will mislead the volunteers on this site. You do understand the vast difference between Java and JavaScript, correct?

Comment: I would even recommend that you don't put them as one... "enter a value in range!"... If I am an end-user I'd be asking wtf are you talking about?  Now, if the message said, "The SAT Math value must be in the range of 200 to 800, please try again."... then I know what you mean.  Programming isn't always about the shortest code; sometimes it's about the code that makes it all comprehensible to the user.

Comment: Agree with @JeremyMiller: it would be better to use three separate if statements so you can provide better feedback to the user if they enter invalid input.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the logic correct, but your implementation is a bit odd. You basically want to do the same thing for every value, so why not check the value as soon as it's entered instead of at the end, like this:

```
class SAT
{
    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static int getInt(final String subject)
    {
        System.out.println("SAT " + subject + ": ");
        final int value = sc.nextInt();
        if(value < 200 || value > 800)
        {
            System.out.println("Did not enter a value in range! (200-800)");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int maths = getInt("Math");
        int reading = getInt("Reading");
        int writing = getInt("Writing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely written, MrLore. +1.  It addresses responsive interaction (by informing the user as they are entering data) and responsible interaction (by informing the user regarding the specific field which needs adjustment).  Kudos!

Comment: What about exception handling? What exception type would I use if they didnt enter a number?

Comment: @juhnellove That's really up to you, I'd probably go with a `java.io.IOException` or make your own `InvalidInputException`.

Answer (score 1):

Use separate if statements and if input is out of range, display which input was out of range so next time user can enter correct input. No shortcut sorry!

Comment: Add a `while` block around **each** input and make the user get each one correct before going to the next one.  When you get tired of repeating yourself, add a method to the class.

Comment: If you have a gui based application, various input widgets or components can be used which restrict user input within specified range.

Answer (score 0):

With repeated code like that, I usually refactor it, like this:

```
// reusable in-range method
private static boolean between(int value, int low, int high) {
    return value >= low && value <= high;
}

// reusable version for this task, because they all share the same range
private static boolean isOK(int value) {
    return between(value, 200, 800);
}
```

then

```
if (!isOK(satMath) || !isOK(satReading) || !isOK(satWriting)) {
    System.out.println("Did not enter a value in range!");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```